# Install Google Apps on AOSP Build

Tags: android, android-source

I have installed [android-6.0.1_r72](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds) *AOSP* Rom on a *Nexus 5* device.
The rom doesn't come with *Google Apps*.

I've tried to install from the [following site](https://devs-lab.com/android-gapps-download.html#StockGoogle_Apps), but after the installation I get

> Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped

Is there a special version of *Google App*s that I have to install?

**UPDATE:**

I found this error in logcat:

```
01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleLocationService

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 3525

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.addGpsStatusListener(ILocationManager.java:741)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.location.LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(LocationManager.java:1522)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at aker.a(:com.google.android.gms:1064)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at akbc.b(:com.google.android.gms:6342)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at akbc.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:279)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

01-17 11:14:52.750  3525  5402 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**UPDATE #2**:

I still get the error, so I've opened an issue in the [GApps git](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/issues/427).

Comment: The best of Google, right on your devices: https://www.android.com/gms/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Three things you are doing wrong:**
1. You generally need to install APK pulled from the same version of Android that you want to run.
2. Don't ever download Google APK from non-Google sites.
**3. In order to install system apps you need to first remount the system partition as read-write.**

Here's how to get and then install genuine Google APK as system apps:

**USE YOUR AOSP BUILD NUMBER TO GET THE MATCHING FACTORY IMAGE**
The link you provided for [**AOSP Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers**](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds) has build numbers that you need to match. 
Search the page for **android-6.0.1_r72** and the corresponding build number is **M4B30X**.

Instead of using untrusted APK from random sites (a terrible idea) you can obtain genuine APK directly from the good folks at Google with the help of their [Factory Images](https://developers.google.com/android/images#hammerhead). 
Search the page for your build number **M4B30X** and download the [image](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/hammerhead-m4b30x-factory-10cfaa5c.zip).
Next, cd into the folder where you downloaded the image and run a check on the SHA-256 Checksum:

```
$ cd Downloads

$ echo "10cfaa5c8ff1753af20283f5e5f938ddebbad094c4e22aadbd925ecdc806e8b3   
  hammerhead-m4b30x-factory-10cfaa5c.zip" | sha256sum -c
```

It should print: hammerhead-m4b30x-factory-10cfaa5c.zip: OK
-If not, download the image again.

**FLASH FACTORY IMAGE AND PULL GENUINE GOOGLE APK**
1. Flash the Factory Image and boot into the system.
2. Activate Developer options and allow 'USB Debugging'
3. Now use ADB to pull(get) the 100% genuine Google Play APK:

```
$ adb pull /system/priv-app/GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
$ adb pull /system/priv-app/Phonesky/Phonesky.apk
$ adb pull /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
```

**FLASH AOSP HAMMERHEAD M4B30X AND PUSH GENUINE GOOGLE APK**
Make sure that you flash either the **userdebug** or **eng** variant.

Push APK files to your sdcard:

```
$ adb push GoogleServicesFramework.apk /sdcard/
$ adb push Phonesky.apk /sdcard/
$ adb push PrebuiltGmsCore.apk /sdcard/
```

**MANUALLY INSTALL APK AS SYSTEM APPS**

```
$ sudo adb shell
```

Locate system partition:
root@hammerhead:/ # mount | grep "/system"
You should get back: 
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

Now mount that system partition as rw(read-write)

```
root@hammerhead:/ # mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system 

root@hammerhead:/ # cd /system/priv-app   
root@hammerhead:/ # mkdir GoogleServicesFramework
root@hammerhead:/ # mkdir Phonesky
root@hammerhead:/ # mkdir PrebuiltGmsCore

root@hammerhead:/ # cp /sdcard/GoogleServicesFramework.apk GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
root@hammerhead:/ # cp /sdcard/Phonesky.apk Phonesky/Phonesky.apk
root@hammerhead:/ # cp /sdcard/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk

root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 755 GoogleServicesFramework
root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 755 Phonesky
root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 755 PrebuiltGmsCore

root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 644 GoogleServicesFramework/GoogleServicesFramework.apk
root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 644 Phonesky/Phonesky.apk
root@hammerhead:/ # chmod 644 PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
```

**CONFIGURE AOSP**

Grant Google Apps Permissions
On your phone, go into **Settings>Apps**
In the overflow menu (gear button upper right corner)
Select **Show system**
Navigate down to **Google Play Store** and allow it all of the permissions.
Do the same for **Google Services Framework** and **Google Play Services (PrebuiltGmsCore)**.
Now make sure ALL of the default AOSP apps have their respective permissions granted.
AOSP by default comes with many permissions turned off.
**Allow ALL permissions for the following apps:**
**Android Keyboard

Browser

Calendar

Camera

Clock

Contacts

Email

Gallery

Launcher3

Messaging

Music

Phone**
*And the ever-janky looking **Search**, if for some reason you don't want to disable it.

Now make sure that Wifi is connected and/or your SIM card is in and providing signal.
**Reboot.**
You should have some brief errors as everything gets sorted, although if the errors continue, another reboot should fix it.

Comment: Thanks you for the details answer. I'll try it and mark it as the solution if it fixes the issue!

Comment: I had to restart the phone after manually installing the APK for **Google Play Store** and **Google Services Framework** to show in **Settings->Apps**. Although, I still don't see **PrebuiltGmsCore** there.. Also, please fix the **priv-app** location in **FLASH FACTORY IMAGE AND PULL GENUINE GOOGLE APK** from `/data/` to `/system/`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.   From inside Settings>Apps PrebuiltGmsCore shows up as Google Play Services.

Comment: Anyone did this with Android10? There isnt any PrebuiltGmsCore there...

Comment: @Paschalis should be called GmsCore.apk

Did you manage do adb pull from the Android 10 factory image? It doesn't allow me to because it's a production build

Comment: I'm on Android 12 and none of the APK's are in /system/priv-app/

Answer (score 7):

[andDevW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41818710/832749) covers the details.

Adding another way to do the second step. Instead of **FLASHing FACTORY IMAGE AND PULL GENUINE GOOGLE APK**,

you can use [simg2img](https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img) to convert the system.img file into a mountable volume

1. Use simg2img to convert your .img file into .raw file

> ```
> simg2img /home/<user>/../aosp/../out/system.img system.raw
> ```

2. mount the raw file as an ext4 external file system volume

> ```
> sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.raw /system
> ```

you will be able to navigate your system.raw image once mounted and you can access /priv-app and other directories to get the apks you need, in the mounted volume at /system.

You can use this to get apks from system.img in factory image releases from Google.

Comment: This is awesome! Simg2img is in Debian's repo and doing it this way is easier than flashing an actual device.

Comment: On my Pixel 4 XL running version 10.0, most of the files were in `product.img` instead. Other than that, yeah; it's totally unnecessary to flash to a device.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on purpose of these apps in your AOSP.

I might be wrong, but in order to install Google Play Service based apps for a custom device it's required to sign an agreement with Google and pass all the verification tests.

Comment: This is true if he's planning to sell the device with Google Play Service preinstalled. Not sure if they prohibit individuals from installing Google Play Services on their personal devices for personal testing use.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is related to Runtime permissions, which is a concept introduced in Android API level 23 (Marshmallow onwards). Prior to this, all the permissions that an Application required where provided during installation implicitly by the user i.e. you are agreeing to give the necessary permissions to the app by installing it.

Google overhauled this. From API level 23 onward, not only an app has to declare all the permissions it needs in manifest but if any of these permissions are categorized as DANGEROUS then application has to request for it at runtime. How an application has to do this - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

I explained all these just to give you a context. In  your case, the problem is that the applications you are trying to install were not designed to run on API level 23 or above. When you installed them they were not implicitly given  some permissions, and since the applications are not requesting for them at runtime, finally they are ending up without the necessary permission to do certain thing  (in your case access the device location).

Long story short, try to find a version of the application designed for Marshmallow and upward. Unfortunately Google made this change in a way that it restricts backward compatibility to some extent. So you can't escape. Find a newer version

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to install `Android 6.0 Gapps` which should be compatible with Android 6.0.1..

Comment: Do let know if it works. And please mark it as answered for future SO references

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstood. I meant that in my original post and inquiry, the Gapps was for the same version as my AOSP build. So, it should've been compatible with my ROM, but it still failed with the error that I posted. Meaning, that it's not an API level issue.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that ? Can you send me the link for one such App ?   As far as I think, it should not be an issue with the custom AOSP. I have faced similar issue and your crash stack strongly suggests the same

Comment: Yep. I'm sure. [Here](https://github.com/opengapps/arm/releases/download/20170116/open_gapps-arm-6.0-pico-20170116.zip) is the link.

Comment: I just noticed this [note](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Notes-for-Android-6.0). Maybe this will resolve the permissions problem. I will update as soon as I check it.

Comment: The issue is more or less caused by the behavior change in Android M :)  Anyways do update the answer.

Comment: **This answer is entirely incorrect.** If what you are saying was true, he could easily fix the problem by simply going into Settings>Apps and for each of the Google Apps hitting 'FORCE STOP', and then manually granting all of it's available permissions. Rebooting would clear up any runtime permissions issue.

Comment: Yes, theoretically this apporach should work too although I have never tried. But from an user point of view, do you expect the user to go to settings page and provide the permission ? That's why applications are asked to check for permission at runtime and ask user for the same if permission not already granted. Anyways in his case the problem was something else since he was playing with a custom ROM (My answer is not marked as Accepted). But We have faced the same problem and my suggestion was based on the same.