# Installing google play services in new android Oreo device(AOSP)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-8.0-oreo

Working On customizing android Oreo device.
Initially in my custom Oreo AOSP google play service are not available.
I have installed `GoogleServicesFramework.apk` and `Phonesky.apk`.

Google maps are getting crash immediately.

```
 08-14 14:53:47.359  2280  2292 I ActivityManager: Killing 4063:com.google.android.apps.maps/u0a67 (adj 900): depends on provider com.google.android.gms/.auth.account.be.legacy.AccountContentProvider in dying proc com.google.android.gms.persistent (adj 0)
 08-14 14:55:22.717   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:22.718  2221  2310 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:22.720  2753  2823 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:22.783   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:22.784  2221  2310 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:22.786  2280  2334 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.340   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.340  2221  2309 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.347   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.348  2221  2309 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
  08-14 14:55:23.359   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.360  2221  2309 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.360  3152  4278 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 4096
  08-14 14:55:23.442   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.443  2221  2310 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.446  3152  4278 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
 08-14 14:55:23.450  3152  4278 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.485   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.489  2221  2309 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.491  3152  4278 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.503   198   284 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.507  2221  2310 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
 08-14 14:55:23.510  3152  4278 E IMGSRV  : :0: PVRSRVMapDmaBuf: offset from mapping dmabuf 0 size 6189056
```

Google play store simply getting white screen.

and I have created basic android maps application, Always showing Goolge play services are updating.

I have followed this link [Install Google Apps on AOSP Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695566/install-google-apps-on-aosp-build)

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. As per my knowledge, you can't simply use the .apk files directly. There are some other .jar files in the `/system/frameworks` folder, and some .so files in `/system/lib` folder, which are required for gapps to function correctly.
2. Are you sure including gapps as a part of your ROM, without license from Google, is even legal?

Overall, much better you provide links to `OpenGapps` in your ROM page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added .jar and .lib files in system directory.While clicking google play store GMAIL app is appear .After giving user name and password (there was problem communicating with google servers) is coming and keep on "update google play service" notification is coming.

Comment: You need the proper `GMSCore.apk`

Comment: CHMcore.apk is trying to copy in the location of /system/priv-app.But out of memory error is generating.I am trying to increase filesystem-->system partition size in u-boot loader buts its system partition memory is not changing.

Comment: Remove any extra apps that can be downloaded from play store, like chrome, play books etc.

Comment: extra apps are not available in the device.Device system partition memory is 653M.,I tried to increase the system partition from U-boot and android device but its not effecting .

Comment: finally i copies every thing.while opening google play store app,this version is not comparable to your device.I have installed latest PrebuiltGmsCore.apk. I am working on Android Oreo AOSP

Comment: But didn't get the right direction.Every time a pope up has arising like "UNFORTUNATELY YOUR GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE HAS BEEN STOPED ".

Comment: could you please mention the jar file which you added in platform to get playstore support